# How to run the code for same value of two variable

Tags: matlab

I have written the following code-

```
  for t=0:4
    for i=5
        B=[1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,2,0;1,1,3,0,0;1,2,2,0,0;1,4,0,0,0;2,3,0,0,0;5,0,0,0,0];
        A=B;
        B(B==0)=inf;
        idx = (A(:,i-t)==1 );
        A = A(idx,:);
    end
end
```

Now the problem is I can run the code for `t=0:i-1` but i want to run this code `for t=0:i`
When I tried with same value of `i and t` then it shows error.It is because as `i-t=0` so it 
means index is `0` but in matlab index never be `0`.

In my case when `i-t=0` then it will take all the value of `A` but i am unable to write the code for this condition.

Matlab experts I need your help and suggestions regrading this code.

Comment: Try this "for i=6" instead of "for i=5".

Comment: I have edited my question.I want to run this code for same value of i and t.For example t=0:10 and i=10

Comment: Your "i" has to be one more than the max of t. Thus it must be 11 now.

Comment: If you want to access to `i=t`, then `i-t=0`. With an index of 0, do you want to acces to the first element of `A`? If so, you can use `idx = (A(:,i-t+1)==1 )`

Comment: @phyrox- actually i want when i-t=0 then it will take all the values of A i.e.  A=[1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,2,0;1,1,3,0,0;1,2,2,0,0;1,4,0,0,0];

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` condition to handle that case specially...

```
if i == t
  idx = (A == 1);
  A = A(idx);
else
  idx = (A(:,i-t)==1 );
  A = A(idx, :);
end
```

Comment: But in that case i am also getting the value which index is not equal to 1.

Comment: i didn't quite get what you are saying. can you explain a bit more the result you got? btw, i edited my solution a bit.